# Elasticsearch - Is it possible to perform a spatial join in a query?

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial, spatial-query, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I would like to perform a spatial join as you would do in [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/joins.html). So far I have explored the various ways outlined with [Geo-shape query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html), but they only were possible by using a single shape or by accessing a shape in a different index by id like here:

```
GET /gdelt/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "geo_shape": {
                    "location": {
                        "indexed_shape": {
                            "index": "ne_countries",
                            "id": "0bnrXnMB0RPtPof-zD-F",
                            "path": "geometry"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to spatially join an index with `geo_point` documents with another or the same index with `geo_shape` documents?